# can anyone give me examples of open subspace of a metric space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Is there anyone who can give me an elegant example of non-empty subspace $A$ which is open in a metric vector space $H$?
I know it cannot be found in $\mathbb R^n$..

Comment: why do you think you can not find open subspace in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Do you want $H$ to be a metric **vector** space and $A$ an open **linear** subspace?

Comment: in any metric space $X$, the set $X$ is an open subset open. So is $\emptyset$.

Comment: sorry for confusing, what I want is non empty proper vector subspace

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik because every finite dimention subspace are closed

Comment: @martini that's exactly what i want

Comment: @IttayWeiss sorry, i mean open vector subspace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If your subspace contains a neighborhood of the zero vector then it contains a small multiple of every vector.  Since its a subspace, it contains every vector.

Comment: what you said is true in $R^n$, but seems not true in general metric vector spaces, like $L^p$

Comment: If $v \neq 0$ then $\frac{\epsilon v}{||v||}$ has norm $\epsilon$. So you can find a multiple of any $v$ contained in the open subset.